# plugin update error wordpress on directory change

Tags: php, wordpress, directory

For security measure I shifted my `wp-config.php` file one level up to root directory.

But whenever a plugin or theme update comes its throw an error and plugin is not updated.

Whenever I place config file to its original directory i am able to update.

So everytime I cannot change directory for update.

So i created

```
/home/gy3gdbd/folder/file.php (config file)
```

and in root directory

```
/home/gy3gdbd/public_html/wp-config.php
```

with below code in `wp-config.php` file:

```
include('/home/gy3gdbd/folder/file.php');
```

Comment: Can you make clear your question in the title?
And although I guess you might need to know how to manage the wpconfig in a different folder, can you rephrase better the question itself?

Comment: do you have a question or this is just an informational manifest?

Comment: apology...for late reply ..As i mentioned i cant update my plugins when i move my config file to /home/gy3gdbd/folder/file.php